# Bulk insert using grails mongodb plugin

Tags: mongodb, grails

I am trying to do DBCollection.insert(List, WriteConcern) from the GORM - MongoDB plugin but I did not find any API that does that. Individual domain save is taking too much time when we need to insert more than 80,000 records.

I have also made all my grails domain objects as stateless in default mapping.

When I tried to get the MongoTemplate and use that for bulk insert with following code:

```
           MongoDatastore datastore = (MongoDatastore)appContext.mongoDatastore
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = datastore.getMongoTemplate(domainClass.gormPersistentEntity)
    mongoTemplate.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.JOURNAL_SAFE);
    def converter = mongoTemplate.converter
    MongoSession mongoSession = (MongoSession)datastore.currentSession
    def collectionName = mongoSession.getCollectionName(domainClass.gormPersistentEntity)
    def collectionObject = getCollectionForEntity(mongoSession, mongoTemplate,domainClass.gormPersistentEntity )
    mongoTemplate.doInsertBatch(collectionName, dataToInsert, converter)
```

The error I am getting is: StackoverflowException :

```
    Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.<init>(HashMap.java:932)
at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.<init>(HashMap.java:932)
at java.util.HashMap.newEntryIterator(HashMap.java:946)
at java.util.HashMap$EntrySet.iterator(HashMap.java:1050)
at java.util.AbstractMap.hashCode(AbstractMap.java:492)
at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:336)
at org.springframework.data.util.TypeDiscoverer.hashCode(TypeDiscoverer.java:485)
at org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.hashCode(ClassTypeInformation.java:39)
at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:351)
at java.util.HashMap.getEntry(HashMap.java:443)
at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:405)
at org.springframework.data.convert.MappingContextTypeInformationMapper.createAliasFor(MappingContextTypeInformationMapper.java:63)
at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.writeType(DefaultTypeMapper.java:177)
at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.writeType(DefaultTypeMapper.java:165)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.addCustomTypeKeyIfNecessary(MappingMongoConverter.java:613)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writePropertyInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:440)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:379)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:366)
```

So now I am trying to use the direct DBCollection after getting it from the MongoTemplate for a given persistent entity. Need some guidance if this API is the only way to proceed?/ also when will bulk insert api in GORM be supported or is there any other work around?

Thanks.

Comment: Using the method on the DBCollection is definitely an OK way to do this - you'll get access to the bulk-insert methods that you're after.

Comment: It would be very fine if gorm would support bulk inserting.